# i accidently deleted some my node modules file while first time creating react app by terminal

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

```
Node.js v18.12.1
PS D:\CS\0. Code\github> npx create-react-app .
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../remove'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\empty\index.js       
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\empty\index.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\fs-extra\\lib\\empty\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\fs-extra\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\createReactApp.js',
    'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

while i was first time creating react app, my internet connection broke at middle. so i deleted some install file,
when i was creating it second time, terminal give me this error.

i tryed `npm install` to reinstal module but its not gime me proper solution
currently
i have  this four file in my working folder

1. node_modules
2. index.html
3. package-lock.json
4. pacakage.json

plz help me to resolve this issue

Comment: uninstall node/npm reinstall. Consider using nvm too.

Comment: Please  add content in your package.json

Answer (score 1):

Some different way I mention here:

Way 1. if you are creating a new project then delete the older project, and also delete it from recycle bin. Now create a new application again.

Way 2. Again the same problem occurs then follow 1st way and then clear your temp file and then try to create a new application.

temp clear steps for windows OS.
press `ctr + R` for open cmd.

1 -> type **"temp"** and delete all files,

2 -> type **"%temp%"** and delete all files,

3 -> type **"prefetch"** and delete all files

Way 3. Reinstall npm.

Answer (score 0):

try this commands in your terminal

> rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

> npm install --force